# How to reach to a faster approach in loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to reach a faster approach to get the same results stated in the HD(variable).
On a small scale of data, it goes fine, but with a larger scale, it takes some time.
if you could, please recommend a faster way, that'd be appreciated.

```
Private Function Excludes() As String
    Dim HL As Long, HI As Long, HV As String, HD As Object
    HL = ActiveSheet.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    HV = ActiveSheet.Range("N" & 15).Value
    For HI = 15 + 1 To HL
        For Each HD In ActiveSheet.Range("N" & HI)
            If HD.Value = "" And ActiveSheet.Range("O" & HI).Value <> "" Then
                HD.Value = "Exclude"
                HD.Offset(0, 2).Value = "0%"
                HD.Offset(0, 3).Value = "No"
            Else
                HD.Value = HD.Value
            End If
        Next HD
    Next HI
End Function
```

Comment: Can you describe what you're working with and what you're tring to do? For example, you declared HD as an object. Why an object?

Comment: I'm trying to loop through each cell in column N starting from cell 15 where the data starts till the last row has data in the same column If No value in the cell, but the cell in O has a criteria (string) then do the results that re under the If statement. to be honest it shouldn't be Object but double as the values in column N are numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Flag Rows in Multiple Columns

[image]

```vb
Sub FlagExcludes()
    
    Dim rg As Range, rCount As Long

    ' It shouldn't be column 'N' because you're looking for blanks in it.        
    With ActiveSheet ' improve!
        Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rg = .Range("O16", .Cells(LastRow, "O"))
        rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    End With
    
    Dim lData(): lData = rg.EntireRow.Columns("N:O").Value
    Dim dData(): dData = rg.EntireRow.Columns("P:Q").Value
    
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        If Len(CStr(lData(r, 1))) = 0 Then ' is blank
            If Len(CStr(lData(r, 2))) > 0 Then ' is not blank
                lData(r, 1) = "Exclude"
                dData(r, 1) = "0%"
                dData(r, 2) = "No"
            End If
        End If
    Next r
        
    rg.EntireRow.Columns("N").Value = lData
    rg.EntireRow.Columns("P:Q").Value = dData

    MsgBox "Excludes flagged.", vbInformation

End Sub
```